# Deleting dynamically created rows with a checked checkbox via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to delete rows that I created in JS which were created with the following code:

```
function createRow() {
var table = document.getElementById("appointment-table")
var row = table.insertRow(0)
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0)
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1)
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2)
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3)
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4)
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5)

var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
checkbox.type = "checkbox"
checkbox.name = "name"
checkbox.value = "value"
checkbox.id = "id"

cell1.appendChild(checkbox)
cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value
cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("email").value
cell4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("address").value
cell5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("phone").value
console.log(table)

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
for (var i = 0; i \<= rows.length; i++) {
if (i % 2 == 0) {
rows\[i\].style.backgroundColor = "#F5F5F5"
} else {
rows\[i\].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
}
}
return table
}
```

and I activate that by clicking a button which opens a form for those inputs.

This was my attempt to read the checked inputs but for some reason it's not able to read rows.

```
function removeSelected(table) {
for (var rowi = table.rows.length; rowi-- \> 0; ) {
var row = table.rows\[rowi\]
var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (var inputi = inputs.length; inputi-- \> 0; ) {
var input = inputs\[inputi\]

      if (input.type === "checkbox" && input.checked) {
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row)
        break
      }
    }

}
}
```

here is my remove button

```
<a href="#deleteEmployeeModal" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" onclick="removeSelected()"><i class="material-icons">&#xE15C;</i>
<span>Remove patient</span></a>
```

here is my create patient

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
   <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
      <h2>Add a new Appointment</h2>
      <label for="Name"><b>Patient Name</b></label>
      <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>
      <label for="Email"><b>Email Address</b></label>
      <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email"                                                                                                                             required>
      <label for="Address"><b>Address</b></label>
      <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address" name="address" required>
      <label for="Phone"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
      <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phone" required>                            
      <label for="N/a"><b></b></label>
      <input id="blank" type="text" placeholder="" name="" required>
      <button type="submit" onclick="createRow()" class="btn">Add Appointment</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

nothing works ever for me

Comment: Press F12 and select the console pane.  Try to delete a row and check the console for error messages.  The problem appears to be that your function removeSelected expects to be passed a table parameter, but your onclick passes nothing.

Comment: how do i pass in my table